# Wordpress Author Template with custom roles

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles, author

I created an author template with the author.php file for wordpress and I recently added a custom role called 'guide_author', although when I try to view their author's page it just shows the details of the first author with a normal wordpress role rather than the custom author's role information.

For example a 'guide_author' with the name of Mike, when I click on his profile page it shows his name as Brent instead since Brent is the first user of the normal wordpress roles.

The code I"m using to get the Author's name in my author.php template file is

```
<?php echo get_the_author() ; ?>
```

Comment: Are you using this tag within The Loop ?

Comment: Ah! good catch. No I am not. How would I do this outside the loop though?

Comment: could you attach code or could you tell, from where you are getting remaining author details like author ID etc.

Comment: Have a look at [the author meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta)